# Get Products list with all product attributes in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, collection, product-collection

I have a statement

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

in file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php in protected function `_getProductCollection()`.

It gives me list of common attributes when I check by

```
print_r($collection->getData());
```

Here I need additional attribute value for attribute 'color'

Some products contain attribute color and some not. When I use the statement `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('color', 'color');` it gives me only product with attribute color

I need all products + products with attribute color

please help me.

Comment: use $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

Comment: it gives only common attribute(entity_id, sku etc ) not attribute color.

Comment: iterate collection object in foreach and see

Answer (score 3):

To get product collection with all attributes use this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Whereas to get all products having attribute color only use

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('color','color');
```

Answer (score 1):

To include additional attributes in standard product lists like in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`, follow these steps:

1. Go to *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes* and select the attribute, you want to include.
2. Set "Used In Product Listing" to "Yes":

   [image: screenshot]
3. If you use the flat catalog indexes, rebuild them.

---

If you use custom code to initialize a product collection, make sure to use

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
```

instead of

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

This way only the attributes, configured as above will be loaded, using the flat index if available. Selecting all attributes with "*" is slow with Magentos EAV models.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the products with all the attributes, use this -

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $_product) {
   echo "<pre>";print_r($_product->getData());
}
```